# carouFredSel is not a function

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling to set up carouFredSel. I'm doing everything correctly - all links work. I'm adding this on online store using smarty templates. I get this error in the chrome console:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).carouFredSel is not a function

head section of **header.tpl**:

```
<!-- jQuery -->       
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<!-- CarouFredSel -->
<script src="http://example.com/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

{literal}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
          jQuery('#carousel').carouFredSel({
                items                : 2,
                direction            : "up",
                scroll : {
                    items            : 1,
                    easing            : "elastic",
                    duration        : 1000,
                    pauseOnHover    : true
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
{/literal}
```

**footer.tpl**:

```
<div id='carousel'>
    <img src='http://example.com/img1.png' width='105' />
    <img src='http://example.com/img2.png' width='110' />
    <img src='http://example.com/img3.png' width='105' />
    <img src='http://example.com/img4.png' width='120' />
    <img src='http://example.com/img5.png' width='105' />
    <img src='http://example.com/img6.png' width='200' />
</div>
```

**css**

```
#carousel img {
    padding: 16px 10px 14px 10px;
}

#carousel {
    width: 1178px;
    height: 126px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The plugin is not being loaded. Have you checked the path to the JS file is correct?

Comment: yes, both jquery and caroufredsel are correct

Comment: What's the *actual* URL for the JavaScript?  In the browser's debugging tools, is it being loaded?

Comment: It's being loaded in debugging tools. it's also working when I click on it from page source http://serwer1449841.home.pl/autoinstalator/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1.js

Comment: any ideas to get this to work?